# What's the format of google.message_id means in GCM?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I need to implement a feature that my app server can get a reply about the android client received the GCM push notification message or not. So I wrote a XMPP app server to connect GCM to achieve Push Notification function.
First, I use http connect to POST message to GCM:

```
        // Create connection to send GCM Message request.
        URL url = new URL("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "key=" + API_KEY);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        // Send GCM message content.
        OutputStream outputStream = conn.getOutputStream();
        outputStream.write(jGcmData.toString().getBytes());

        // Read GCM response.
        InputStream inputStream = conn.getInputStream();
        String resp = IOUtils.toString(inputStream);
        System.out.println(resp);
```

I get a success response:

> {"message_id":5112490523075894883}

Then my app get the notification :

```
public class MyGcmListenerService extends GcmListenerService {

private static final String TAG = "MyGcmListenerService";

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
    String message = data.getString("message");
    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + from);
    Log.d(TAG, "Message: " + message);

    String messageId = data.getString("google.message_id");
    Log.d(TAG, "Message id : " + messageId);
    .....
   }
    ....
 }
```

I get the resposne log :

> Message id : 0:1473650899594799%744ab298f9fd7ecd

my XMPP server to get the upstream message from GCM :

```
private void sendAck(String to, String msg_id) {
JsonObject jPayload = new JsonObject();
jPayload.addProperty("to", to);
jPayload.addProperty("message_id", msg_id);
jPayload.addProperty("message_type", "ack");

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
final String payload = gson.toJson(jPayload);
Stanza stanza = new Stanza() {
  @Override
  public CharSequence toXML() {
    return wrapWithXML(payload);
  }
};

logger.info("sending ack: " + stanza);
smackCcsClient.sendStanza(stanza);
}
```

Of course, my XMPP server received the response.

```
<code>
    sending ack: <message><gcm xmlns="google:mobile:data">{
    "to": "eE3z_9KSnME:APA91bG36ijVaoKBXi-  H2Pi4cieFp2_HYmXsAZ5M2pkHLqS2Xxyr1LwfIPfbO_ZfcVSEO_y9r2H76y-V1Ql3x9jGZ_apvTkZUTPEWD9972gDHBFI0Glb04ajRliULbc19LHiiPaOWZ_2",
   "message_id": "0:1473650899594799%744ab298f9fd7ecd",
   "message_type": "ack"}</gcm></message>
</code>
```

I found the message id in XMPP server and client app is the same. But what's the format **"0:1473650899594799%744ab298f9fd7ecd"** means? What's the relationship between **"0:1473650899594799%744ab298f9fd7ecd"** and **"5112490523075894883"**?

I want to know after I sent the message to GCM, what's this two responses message_id one-to-one correspondence between http call and XMPP server.

I tried more times:

1. > server receive message id  : 5242809308476536544
   >   client receive message id  : 0:1473670928604617%744ab298f9fd7ecd
2. > server receive message id  : 9216122830970130711
   >   client receive message id  : 0:1473671350517288%744ab298f9fd7ecd
3. > server receive message id  : 5133661789983197332
   >   client receive message id  : 0:1473671927731592%744ab298f9fd7ecd

I do need your help to find out what's the relationship. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there's no relationship between those message IDs since HTTP and XMPP are two different connection servers.

As mentioned in [Implementing GCM Server](http://www.androiddocs.com/google/gcm/server.html), it is for you to decide which GCM connection servers you want to use to implement your app server.

Furthermore, as described in documentations, `message_id` is a string that uniquely identifies the associated message for HTTP or XMPP connections.

For detailed information, you may also check the following references:

- [Interpreting a downstream message response](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#interpret-downstream)
- [Interpreting a downstream XMPP message response](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/xmpp-server-ref#interpreting-a-downstream-xmpp-message-response)

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I try to build a xmpp server to send downstream message to GCM.